# How to draw rotated text in a CALayer in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I have an aircraft plotting application on Mac OS X that uses multiple CALayers. I would like to draw the runway number rotated correctly but I don't understand why my rotation doesn't work. My view is flipped.

Here is my code:

```
void drawTextAtAngle (CGContextRef context, NSString *label, NSPoint pt, double angle)
{    
   CGContextSaveGState (context);

   /*
    * Draw a blob for the center - this proves 'pt' is at the correct place
    */
   CGContextSetLineWidth (context, 2.5);
   NSRect rect = CGRectMake (pt.x - 5.0, pt.y - 5.0, 5.0 * 2.0, 5.0 * 2.0);
   CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (context, 50.0 / 255.0, 118.0 / 255.0, 193.0 / 255.0, _lineAlpha);
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 50.0 / 255.0, 118.0 / 255.0, 193.0 / 255.0, _lineAlpha);
   CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect (context, rect);

/*
 * Tried some of this with mixed results.
 */
//   CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
//   transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (transform, pt.x, pt.y);
//   CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, transform);
//   CGContextRotateCTM (context, angle);


   /*
    * Don't know what this does but if not here text draws backwards.
    */
   CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, transform);

  /*
   * This rotates the view but around the centre bit I need to rotate it
   * around 'pt'.
   */
  CGContextRotateCTM (context, angle);

//CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI / 2.0);
//CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle);
//[self setAffineTransform:transform];
//   CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, transform2);


  /*
   * Some of this is apparently deprecated in 10.10.
   */
  CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica", 14.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
  CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, pt.x, pt.y, [label UTF8String], [label length]);

  CGContextRestoreGState (context);
  }
```

This is what is drawn:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB3pB.jpg)

The '29' runway label should be over the small blue circle which the code above commented "draw blob" draws but the rotation doesn't seem to be able to rotate about that point. It's far too hight and to the right which seems to show the rotation is around the layers centre not the centre of the text.

Thanks, regards Rob.

I think I may have cracked this:

```
void drawTextAtAngle (CGContextRef context, NSString *label, NSPoint pt, double angle)
{
   CGContextSaveGState (context);

   /*
    * Move the rotation point and rotate around
    * that point.
    */       
   CGContextTranslateCTM (context, pt.x, pt.y);
   CGContextRotateCTM (context, angle);

   /*
    * Now that 0,0 is at the point we want the text draw there
    */
   pt = NSMakePoint (0.0, 0.0);

   CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica", 14.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, pt.x, pt.y, [label UTF8String], [label length]);

   CGContextRestoreGState (context);
}
```

I now need to workout how big 'label' is so that I can centre on it, but that's another problem for later.